# Relative time using am-time-ago not working with ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to show relative time in angularJS using angular-moment plugin.

When I add code below on my html template directly it is working and showing correct relative time

```
<span am-time-ago='currentTime' class='item-note' ></span>
```

But if I use ng-bind-html and try to show relative time using scope variable, it is not working. Here is the code I have used.

```
//html
<div id="{{parameterGuid}}" ng-bind-html="userChat">

</div>

//js
$scope.userChat = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div am-time-ago='currentTime' class='item-note'></div>");
```

As per my requirement I need to use ng-bing-html, so can anyone suggest how to show relative time in this case?

Comment: That is because `ng-bind-html` doesn't `$compile` the HTML (in the Angular sense). In other words, Angular doesn't evaluate the HTML for directives

Comment: Why can't you just create a directive?

Comment: very correct @NewDev . `element.append` with `$compile`d element will do the trick from directive

Comment: Thanks guys.. I will try directive